# C# combo-box in grid view not populating correctly

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

i have desktop application in which i am using data gridview control. i want to use a combo-box in each grid row that holds 2 items (Sale, Return). i am as far as single row concerns, i am not getting any issue but when i enter any other row, it shows me double comboboxes in each row and tripple for third row and so on. 
second issue that i am facing is that i am not getting both of two items that i am trying to insert through items.add method. below is code that i am using to insert combobox column in grid

```
custCartGrid.Rows.Add();
            GridRow = custCartGrid.Rows.Count-1;
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dcom = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            dcom.HeaderText = "Combobox";
            dcom.Items.Add("Sale");
            dcom.Items.Add("Return");
            custCartGrid.Columns.Add(dcom);
```

please help me in this..

Comment: Looks like this code been executing every time when you add new row, post the complete method.

Comment: yes this code is executing every time

Comment: in every time i insert row in Grid, i want an Combo-box there

Comment: Move this code outside, I would suggest where you creat custCartGrid or form load.

Comment: this code is on button click event

Comment: Move it to form_load.

Comment: on form load the problem is same except it loads only one time so i am not able to enter another row

Comment: Post your complete code, I'll show you where you can make the change.

Comment: @HariPrasad this is the exact code that i am using behind button click event